# Is there an equivalent of p.p. for non-signed printed letters?

Tags: letter-writing

When signing a letter on behalf of a colleague the convention would be to write:

> My signature
>
> **p.p.** Their Name

However I am currently in the position where a document will go unsigned but I will be **printing** the name of *someone else*.  Is there an abbreviation to indicate this or should I go with p.p.?

Comment: I have revise my answer. (Note that p.p. must be placed before your signature.)

Comment: See wikipedia [per procurationem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_procurationem) article, which shows three forms and says "The correct usage is the subject of some debate."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P.P. stands for per pro which is an abreviation of per procurationem, meaning by the agency of.

As such I do not see that printing or signing the name would make any difference, so I guess it would be just

> p.p Their name

without any signature. I have to add that this is just from personal understanding, not experience. I have never personally seen a letter that uses p.p.

Comment: A caveat is that an unsigned letter isn't binding so it doesn't matter what you put, to be honest. PP is used most often as a legal  means by which you can assign culpability.  Other than that, use it however you want.